# C++ Program Menu Confusion

Tags: c++, xcode

In this C++ program, I keep getting an error that says "editor placeholder in source file" for case 'fa': findArea. I do not know what the problem is. I have tried to change it up to another name but haven't succeeded.

```
int main () 
{ 
 void findArea(double);
 void quit();
 void printHelp();

 case 'h':
 case 'H': printHelp(); //help text.
 break;

 case 'q':
 case 'Q': quit();  //quit program.
 break;

 case 'fa':
 case 'FA': findArea(); //find area of rectangle.
 break;
 }
 void quit(){ // end program
 cout << "Ending!"  << endl;
 }
 void printHelp(){ // help text

 cout << "Supported commands: \n"
       << "fa. find area./n"
       << "h. print help./n"
       << "q. quit./n"    
   }
 void findArea(){
  area = length * width;
 }
```

Comment: There's so many problems with the code you show that I don't know where to begin. Who is teaching you C++? What resources or books do you use?

Comment: Haven't seen that error before, but you may want to move the prototypes for your functions outside of `main`.  You also want to make sure your argument list is the same between your prototype and the actual implementation.

Comment: Also read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). And learn how to [edit] your question to show us a proper [mcve] that you copy-paste into the question. And if the code you already show is your actual and full code you try to build, then see my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have

```
 void findArea(double);
 void quit();
 void printHelp();
```

inside of your main function.  Normally these would be outside of any function.

2. `void findArea(double);` is declared, but `case 'FA': findArea();` is used and `void findArea(){}` is defined.  Change:

```
void findArea(double);
```

to

```
void findArea();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**.
 *Prob your code had* : 
You had function declaration in main() which is not allowed. There was one more mistake you had argument type double in area but in function body of area it was void so it is a argument mismatch compiler error. 
Also your code has case statement without switch(). there are lot more errors like you had not declared variables not even taking input.

```
   #include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
  void findArea();
  void printHelp();
  void quit();
  int main ()
  { 
      char ch; 
      cout<<"Enter choice \n";
      cout<<"h for Help \n";
     cout<<"q for Quit \n"; 
    cout<<"fa to find area \n"; 
     cin>>ch;
      switch (ch)
      {
     case 'h':
    case 'H': printHelp(); //help text. 
                    break;
      case 'q':
       case 'Q': quit(); //quit program.
                      break; 
      case 'f':  
      case 'F':       findArea(); 
                           break;
      } 
 return 0;
  }
  void quit()
  { 
    cout << "Ending!" << endl;
  }  
   void printHelp()
   {
  // help text
 cout << "Supported commands: \n"; 
  cout<< "f. find area.\n" ;
 cout<< "h. print help.\n" ;
 cout<< "q. quit./n" ;
  } 
  void findArea()
  { 
   double l,w,area;
   cout<<"Enter Length \n";     
   cin>>l;
   cout<<"Enter Width \n";
   cin>>b;

   area = l * w; 
   cout<<"\n\tArea = "<<area;
   }
```

Comment: Also `void quit();` not `void quit():` If you are going to suggest some code you should try to compile first. I don't think the OP has the skill to fix any typos you make. There are other mistakes as well.

Comment: I edited and yes you are saying true but I wrote this code on phone. I am not having laptop with me right now

Comment: Well you have `case` without `switch`, multi character literals e.g. `'fa'`. Maybe more

Comment: I fixed this issue

Comment: Code-only answers without explanations about the problem or what was changed are really not good. Especially if they still contain part of the error being asked about. Please read about [how to write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Okay thank you but now it is also giving me an error about having a multi-letter case. I can't change the case to just 'f', I need to keep it as 'fa'

Comment: Yes you can only use character in case .  Character is a single letter. So fa is not allowed. Use f only